# Browser does not apply the new css after save, restart and clearing all cookies

Tags: css, wordpress, browser

I am using wordpress as my cms and building a website. I use Graphene as my theme, as I modify the style.css through the administration menu (and verify the change via vi editor), I see that the change is there.

Now when I open my website, and right click Inspect element, I still see a old value of my "height parameter".

So I deleted all cookies, temp files from Chrome. And relaunched the website, still the old height values persist. What am I missing here ?

All sites I have referred to hint at clearing cookies, temp files.

Edit : I am running the wordpress server on my localhost.
Edit : added image

[image: Inspect Element]

Comment: Have you double checked that you are editing the correct file in the correct environment?

Comment: I edit using the Appearance->Header, and verify using vi on /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/graphene/style.css. All changes from the admin console are reflected to the style.css.

Comment: I wonder why does it show 98px crossed.. ?

Comment: Because `#header_img_link` is defined after `style.css` is included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the page in  incognito mode in Chrome (ctrl + shift + n ) just to make sure the page is loading the updated css file.

Comment: thanks, but still I am seeing height 198. I modified the height to 90 its not showing up.

Comment: notice the image i uploaded, seems like there is a style.css that is overriding my theme style.css, how do I find out where this style.css is ?

Comment: you have certain properties defined in #header_img_link which are overriding the properties defined in style.css.Check the style definitions defined in #header_img_link.

Comment: I am not a css or html developer. Can you let me know how to identify where this override is happening ? In which css or html file ?

Comment: You have to remove the style definitions for #header_img_link{width:960px;height:198px;} .
View page source (ctrl + U). Open the css files that are being loaded in the page.
Search for header_img_link (ctrl+f) in them. Then remove it from the corresponding file.

Comment: I did a search in files, for "header_img" and found only style.css (in the graphene theme folder). The view source did show a whole lot of css's but the search did not show any that had "header_img".

Comment: Ok, I did a search of "header_img" in the view source, and found "#header_img_link{width:960px; height:198px;}" :). Now where is the front page for graphene theme ?

Comment: check the file theme-head.php in includes folder. search for "header_img" .

Comment: Ok, found it.. wp-content/themes/graphene/includes/theme-setup.php
 has a value HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT which is set in wp-content/themes/graphene/includes/theme-head.php /* Link header image */
 if ( $graphene_settings['link_header_img'] && (HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH != 900 || HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT != 90) ) {
  $style .= '#header_img_link{width:'. HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH .'px; height:'. HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT .'px;}';
 }

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the CSS file you're editing is not the one your website is using.

Double check that the path to the CSS file you're expecting to change is the one you're changing in the backend.